# Null pointer on not null index?

Tags: java, android

Like in subject. I got null pointer, how it is possible ?

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button, button2;
    TextView textView, textView2;
    String abc;
    public List list = new ArrayList<>();
    int size;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list.add("abc");
        abc = (String) list.get(0);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.setText(abc);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  size = list.size();
                textView2.setText(size);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your xml file here.

Comment: you should initialise variables first.

Comment: @jobs please check my ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to do `findViewById` to your Controls in `OnCreate()`

```
button2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnID);
textView2 =(textView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

**Sample code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybtnID);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView2 = (textView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    list.add("abc");
    abc = (String) list.get(0);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ){
            textView.setText(abc);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ){
            size = list.size();
            textView2.setText(size);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You  are missing 
`findViewById` for all your widget

i.e.

```
 Button button, button2;
 TextView textView, textView2;
 button = findViewById(R.id.id_of_button_1); // same for button2,textview,textview2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  are missing `findViewById` for all your widget

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnID);
button2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

textView = =(textView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView2 =(textView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

**Sample Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button, button2;
    TextView textView, textView2;
    String abc;
    public List list = new ArrayList<>();
    int size;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnID);
        button2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        textView = =(textView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2 =(textView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        list.add("abc");
        abc = (String) list.get(0);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.setText(abc);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  size = list.size();
                textView2.setText(size);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize with `findById(R.id.myBtn)` like everyone is saying. Or programatically like `button = new Button(this);`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

You forgot to add `findViewById`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button, button2;
    TextView textView, textView2;
    String abc;
    public List list = new ArrayList<>();
    int size;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button); 
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 

        list.add("abc");
        abc = (String) list.get(0);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.setText(abc);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  size = list.size();
                textView2.setText(size);
            }
        });

    }


}
```